# rxjs observable in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, header, observable

I have a confusion about the observable in rxjs
Is it follow the observer design pattern? if so, Should its subscriber get notified of the latest value or any change?

Let me show you an example.

this is my user service

```
    login(userData): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.APIURL,userData).pipe(
      map((user: any) => user.firstName),
      tap((name) => {
        localStorage.setItem('userName', name);
        localStorage.setItem('isLogin', 'true');
      })
      );
    }
   private nameObservable:Observable<string>=new Observable<string>(observer=>{
      observer.next(localStorage.getItem("userName"))
    })
    getName(): Observable<string> {
      return this.nameObservable;
    }
    logout() {
      localStorage.removeItem("userName");
      localStorage.removeItem("isLogin");
    }
```

this is my header component

```
    ngOnInit() {
   this.isLogin=!!localStorage.getItem("isLogin")
    this.userService.getName()
    .subscribe((userName)=>{
         this.name=userName
       })
   }
```

and login button call that login function

the issue is my header doesn't get notified when I hit the login button it needs to be reloaded.
I know I should use Subject or behaviorSubject instead of observable but my question again is:

- -Is it follows the observer design pattern? if so, Should its subscriber get notified of the latest value or any change?

  - if yes, Does my header didn't get the changes in the observable because it should call the ngOnInit function to get the value in
    localStorage after changes?
  - if not, I shouldn't use it to keep track of changes in some value. It's for async handling only?
  - What about ParamMap in the ActivatedRoute? it's observable and if I change a param in the URL with some button on the page then
    subscribe to ParamMap and catch that param in ngOnInit(), it gets the
    value changed with every click!! or it's something built in?

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a typo. You are setting an item on key `username` but then asking for `userName` try fixing that. A little bit clunky with the manual `subscribe()`, but it should work. Remember to unsubscribe as well.

Comment: The typo was in the question not my code and it doesn't work. The question has been corrected.

Comment: There are still more problems with the code. 1) it is still `username` in component. 2) `this.http.post` requires 2 params, the url and body to post. 3) When or where is `login()` called?

Comment: Thanks for your care but I'm trying to understand more about observable, not solving an issue . Although you can find my small demo about displaying the username after a fake login button with observable and behavior subject [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4dpiye?file=src/app/user.service.ts)